# Receive POST Data equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, http-post

I'm supposed to receive POST data on my web page from a web form and store it. I have the following line of code to receive it using PHP.

```
$jdata = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

What is the equivalent of this in ASP.NET / C#?

In other words, how do I receive POST Data and decode it using C#?

Comment: `Request.Form["data"]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your next question will be how to update a database using ASP.NET, so I have answered that question as well as this one in the following code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["Name"] == null) Response.End();
    if (Request.Form["ID"] == null) Response.End();

    //Connection string
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=sqlsvr.net;Initial Catalog=ohsrespirator;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd");

    //Set a command
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table_Name SET Column_Name = @value1, Column_ID = @value2", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request.Form["Name"] as string;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Request.Form["ID"] as string;

    //Open connection and execute update
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch { }
    finally { if (conn != null) conn.Close(); }
}
```

P.S. You may also need this if your data is coming in as JSON:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var JSON = JSS.Deserialize<dynamic>(Request.Form["POSTED_JSON"]);
```